# resizing frame by window manage under AnyDesk disassociates emacs buffers' dimensions

Tags: frames, remote, x-window

I'm trying a new (to me) remote desktop tool AnyDesk (v.5.5.4).  I'm attaching to Ubuntu18 system at work from a Ubuntu19 system at home.  When I resize an emacs frame with the mouse, the menu bar, the mode line and mini-buffer and text area do not resize.

None of the resizing commands I've tried have had any effect.  At root I think it's a failing of AnyDesk but I'm not having any luck at that end and am hoping there's a manual resizing within emacs which might counter the AnyDesk issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my windows machine. I was not able to resize the anydesk window on my external monitor and it occupied the whole screen without any resize option.

Workaround:

This issue is due to scaling of your os(in my case windows)

Go to display setting scale the windows to 110% or more and then you should be able to resize the anydesk window.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, it's working pretty well for me these days.  Not sure what fixed this for me (some updates probably)